# How to map table name to EF Entity?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I have been using EF Code First for 1 month. My project needs to work with many tables (over 100 tables of data) and they will be changed many times in the future. It hard to control and take time to add the migration.

So is there any solution to skip the add-migration step, just create the table in the database and create a mapping to the Entity?

Example:

In database I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(255),
    Description VARCHAR(1000)
);
```

I want to map it to the following entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public Id int {get; set;}
   public Name string {get; set;}
   public Description string {get; set;}
}
```

My expected solution is something like this:

```
CreateMap("dbo.MyTable", MyEntity)
```

Comment: you can use [Table("MyTable")] attribute on your entity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class MyEntity
{
   public Id int {get; set;}
   public Name string {get; set;}
   public Description string {get; set;}
}
```

If you don't actually want to run the migrations, I suggest create them anyway and comment out the relevant code before you run them. That way you will be well set up for the occassion  when you do actually want to run them.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the entity maps by overriding the method called `OnModelCreating` in your DbContext:

Then you can add some maps similar to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(m => {
     m.ToTable("MyTable", "dbo");
})
```

Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables

EDIT: I don't like adding annotation directly to my entity as I prefer to centralize it in one place. Easier to manage. After all I guess it's a question of preferences :)